# Sendmail relay alters recipient email?

Tags: smtp, centos7, sendmail

Hello I am trying to set up sendmail on a Centos 7 server to relay mails from a local program to our main mail server. I have configured sendmail.mc with the following, mail.[domain].com is our SMTP server:

> define('SMART_HOST', 'mail.[domain].com')dnl

And

> FEATURE(`nullclient',`mail.[domain].com') dnl

This is the sendmail log from trying to send this mail:

```
Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21975]: w7O8qIUJ021975: Authentication-Warning: centos7.[domain]: openproject set sender to info@[domain].com using -f

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21975]: w7O8qIUJ021975: from=info@[domain].com, size=2587, class=-60, nrcpts=1, msgid=<5b7fc7423c037_218b2acdfb6fcf7c2088c@centos7.[domain].mail>, relay=openproject@localhost

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21976]: w7O8qIMw021976: from=<info@[domain].com>, size=2854, class=-60, nrcpts=1, msgid=<5b7fc7423c037_218b2acdfb6fcf7c2088c@centos7.[domain].mail>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21975]: w7O8qIUJ021975: to=dennis@[domain].com, ctladdr=info@[domain].com (988/982), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=140587, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (w7O8qIMw021976 Message accepted for delivery)

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: STARTTLS=client, relay=mail.[domain].com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384, bits=256/256

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMw021976: to=<dennis@[domain].com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=230854, relay=mail.[domain].com. [192.168.111.10], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMw021976: w7O8qIMw021978: DSN: User unknown

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMw021978: to=<info@[domain].com>, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30000, relay=mail.[domain].com. [192.168.111.10], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMw021978: w7O8qIMx021978: return to sender: User unknown

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMx021978: to=postmaster, delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30000, relay=mail.[domain].com. [192.168.111.10], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMw021978: Losing ./qfw7O8qIMw021978: savemail panic

Aug 24 11:52:18 centos7 sendmail[21978]: w7O8qIMw021978: SYSERR(root): savemail: cannot save rejected email anywhere
```

Now based on what the sendmail log says it seems as if my email dennis@[domain].com does not exist which is strange because it does. But if I look at the log in the mail server it says a slightly different thing:

```
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.667: Session 471387; child 0001
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.667: Accepting SMTP connection from 192.168.111.15:42300 to 192.168.111.10:25
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.670: --> 220 xxxx ESMTP MDaemon 18.0.2; Fri, 24 Aug 2018 11:52:18 +0300
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.672: <-- EHLO centos7.[domain]
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.673: --> 250-xxxxx Hello centos7.[domain] [192.168.111.15], pleased to meet you
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.673: --> 250-ETRN
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.673: --> 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 PLAIN
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.673: --> 250-8BITMIME
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.674: --> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.674: --> 250-STARTTLS
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.674: --> 250 SIZE
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.683: <-- STARTTLS
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.683: --> 220 2.7.0 Ready to start TLS
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.705: SSL negotiation successful (TLS 1.2, 256 bit key exchange, 256 bit AES encryption)
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: <-- EHLO centos7.[domain]
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: --> 250-xxxxx Hello centos7.[domain] [192.168.111.15], pleased to meet you
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: --> 250-ETRN
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: --> 250-AUTH LOGIN CRAM-MD5 PLAIN
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: --> 250-8BITMIME
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: --> 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.716: --> 250 SIZE
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.724: <-- MAIL From:<info@mail.[domain].com> SIZE=3046
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.726: --> 250 2.1.0 Sender OK
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.754: <-- RCPT To:<dennis@mail.[domain].com>
Fri 2018-08-24 11:52:18.755: Sender attempted to deliver message to unknown address
```

So for some reason the domain part in the from and to email addressed have been corrupted. The mail server thinks someone is trying to send to dennis@mail.[domain].com when in reality I want to send to dennis@[domain].com.

I have no idea why it does this.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, almost embarrasing, but I kept going through the sendmail.mc file and found the following bit that I had activated earlier, I recommented the LOCAL_DOMAIN line and things started working.

```
dnl # Also accept email sent to "localhost.localdomain" as local email.
dnl #
LOCAL_DOMAIN(`[domain].com')dnl
```